# Webstorm 9 Fonts Weird with OS X Yosemite

Tags: fonts, webstorm, osx-yosemite

How can I make the fonts work again on Webstorm 9 running on OS X Yosemite?[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was a result of using Java 1.7 instead of 1.6.  After installing Java 1.6 again, everything works.